# How to handle release candidates in git-flow

Tags: workflow, git-flow, release-management, release-candidate

We're working by the [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) workflow. Typically we release some release candidates (RC, v1.0.0-rc.0) before we ship the final release (v1.0.0).

To do so, we have a release branch (`release/1.0.0`). The release candidates are just *tags* within that branch. The release branch is not merged into `main` until we have a final release.

Today we discussed whether we should open *a release branch for every release candidate* (e.g. `release/1.0.0-rc.0) and merge these into main whenever the candidate is released.

Any opinions on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if each of the previous release candidates are *reachable* by the newest one, then they could be on the same branch, and therefore there isn't any benefit to having separate branches for each.

If you wish to make a new release candidate that does not start from the current release candidate (e.g. perhaps you need to back up a few commits, or even start over), then that would be a good time to consider creating a new branch.

I assume once you merge into `main` you can delete all of the release branches, whether they were fully merged into `main` or not. Since you still have the old release versions tagged that you didn't use, you could always go back to them if you wish, even without the branches.